# Can't install lamp-server^ after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: installation, 13.04, 13.10, package-management, lamp

I installed 13.04 because installing with 13.10 directly wouldn't work in UEFI mode.

When I `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` it fails with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
 apache2-bin : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
 apache2-data : Conflicts: apache2.2-common but 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
 apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can this be fixed so that I can install lamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a backup of `/etc/apache2`, then try:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

Then try installing `lamp-server^` again.

Comment: Thank you for looking!  It looks like apache2 wasn't even installed.

Comment: Before starting, is everything else up to date: `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Yessir, all up to date.  I'm currently installing the individual packages directly, and that seems to work.  Go figure.  Backports was previously checked.  :/